# Integration by parts (like Walli's integrals)

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$I(n)=2n\displaystyle\int _0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\:\left(\sin^{\left(2n-1\right)}\left(\theta \right)\cos^2\left(\theta \right)\right)\,d\theta$

show that I(n) can be written as  $I(n)=2nI(n-1)-2nI(n)$ and as I(n)=$(\frac{2n}{2n+1}(I(n-1))$    for n$\ge$1

So far Ive't tried using integration but I end up going around in circles. Can someone please try to show me how to do this? Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which way you want to go but lets go from the (assumed) definition
$$
I(n) = 2n\int_0^{b}\sin^{2n-1} x \cos^2 x dx = 2n\int_0^{b}\sin^{2n-1} x \left(1-\sin^2 x\right) x dx \\
$$
thus we get
$$
I(n) = -2n\int_0^b\sin^{2n+1}xdx+2n\int_0^b\sin^{2n-1}xdx
$$
integrals have the same form 
$$
\int_0^b \sin^{m}xdx 
$$
are integrated by parts to yield
$$
du = \sin x \to u = -\cos x dx\\
v = \sin^{m-1}x \to dv = (m-1)\sin^{m-2}x\cos x dx
$$
so 
$$
\int_0^b \sin^{m}xdx = \left[-\cos x \sin^{m-1}x\right]_0^b+(m-1)\int_0^b\sin^{m-2}x\cos^2x dx
$$
or
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{m}xdx =(m-1)\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{m-2}x\cos^2x dx
$$
so comparing with the second equation I wrote
$$
I(n) = -2n\int_0^b\sin^{2n+1}xdx+2n\int_0^b\sin^{2n-1}xdx = -2n\left((2n+1-1)\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2n+1-2}x\cos^2x dx\right)+2n\left((2n-1-1)\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2n-1-2}x\cos^2x dx\right)
$$
or simply
$$
I(n) =-2n\left(2n\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2n-1}x\cos^2x dx\right)+2n\left((2n-2)\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2n-2 -1}x\cos^2x dx\right)
$$
and finally
$$
I(n) = -2n\left(2n\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2n-1}x\cos^2x dx\right)+2n\left((2(n-1))\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2(n-1) -1}x\cos^2x dx\right)
$$